# Can hardhat deploy contract by metamask?

Tags: remix, metamask, testnets, hardhat-deploy

I read the doc: https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network

This is the config file:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

// Go to https://www.alchemyapi.io, sign up, create
// a new App in its dashboard, and replace "KEY" with its key
const ALCHEMY_API_KEY = "KEY";

// Replace this private key with your Goerli account private key
// To export your private key from Metamask, open Metamask and
// go to Account Details > Export Private Key
// Beware: NEVER put real Ether into testing accounts
const GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY = "YOUR GOERLI PRIVATE KEY";

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks: {
    goerli: {
      url: `https://eth-goerli.alchemyapi.io/v2/${ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`,
      accounts: [GOERLI_PRIVATE_KEY]
    }
  }
};
```

So I have export the private key of my account in metamask.

I want to know, why not hardhat deploy contract by metamask which stored the account, so we do not need to export a private key? It seems Remix can deploy contract by metamask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hardhat is a backend platform. Metamask lives in your browser. They are not meant to communicate like that. So you can't deploy your contract through Hardhat by utilizing private keys inside Metamask.

I would say this is mostly due to two factors:

1. Security. Browsers are all the time exposed to the wide internet and they need lots of different security factors. Hardhat lives only in the backend and has a lot less attack surface.
2. Integration challenges. Since hardhat is a backend tool, it would be possibly quite difficult to integrate it directly with a browser wallet.

They are simply meant for different purposes.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved with the help of this npm library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat_metamask_client

- The approach of the library is a little tricky due to the fact that hardhat doesn't meant to do such things.

Comment: That works for me. Thanks!